# Limited Admin or Delegated Admin profile in Salesforce

Tags: administration, profile, security, permissions

So this is the conundrum I am in, we are wanting to store HR sensitive information within salesforce such as salary info and SSN the issue is that we have part of our development team has admin access for obvious reason, is it possible to have a profile that would retain the same privileges as a regular admin minus the ability to assign certain permission set and profiles?

I have read a little about delegated administrators but I am not sure it would fit the bill based on some of the limitations on this page:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_delegate.htm

Does anyone have experience with that? or encounter a similar problem? Any ideas on how to restrict access to data on custom object from admins?

Comment: Any suggestions for anyone? Surely someone has ran into this issue before!